# how to pass parameter from partial View to controller class in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want redirect details of specific item after click on is name in home page. How can I do that?

This is `home controller` of my project:

```
namespace WEB1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private projectDBEntities db = new projectDBEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult topPlace()
        {
            var top_place = db.Places.OrderByDescending(a => a.place_rate).Take(6).ToList();
            return PartialView("_topPlace", top_place);
        }

        public ActionResult topServices()
        {
            var top_service = db.service_provider.OrderByDescending(a => a.Sp_rate).Take(6).ToList();
            return PartialView("_topService",top_service);
        }


    }
}
```

This is `TDS controller`:

```
namespace WEB1.Controllers
{
    public class TDSController : Controller
    {
        private projectDBEntities db = new projectDBEntities();

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Place place = db.Places.Find(id);
            if (place == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(place);
        }



        public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            var places = db.Places.Include(p => p.city).OrderByDescending(s => s.place_rate);
            if(Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber =(page ?? 1);
            return View(places.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }

        public ActionResult Historical(int? page)
        {
            var places = db.Places.Include(p => p.city).OrderByDescending(s => s.place_rate).Where(s => s.Place_type == "Historical");
            if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(places.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }


        public ActionResult Religious(int? page)
        {
            var places = db.Places.Include(p => p.city).OrderByDescending(s => s.place_rate).Where(s => s.Place_type == "Religious");
            if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(places.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }

        public ActionResult Scenic(int? page)
        {
            var places = db.Places.Include(p => p.city).OrderByDescending(s => s.place_rate).Where(s => s.Place_type == "Scenic");
            if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(places.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }


        public ActionResult Educational(int? page)
        {
            var places = db.Places.Include(p => p.city).OrderByDescending(s => s.place_rate).Where(s => s.Place_type == "Educational");
            if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(places.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

This is `top places partail view`:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WEB1.Models.Place>
<div class="homebody">

    <h3>Most Populer Places</h3>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="item1">
                <p class="name">@Html.ActionLink(item.Place_name, "Details", "TDS", new { id = item.PID })</p>
                <p class="cattype">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Place_location)</p>
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.city.Cityname)</p>
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.place_rate)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use of

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Place_name, "Details", "TDS", new { id = item.PID })
```

is using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) and adding the `item.PID` as a `htmlAttribute`, not a route value. You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) so that you code will be

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Place_name, "Details", "TDS", new { id = item.PID }, null)
```

Comment: I want to know what is the reason for adding null? what is route value?

Comment: Adding null as the last parameter means your calling the correct overload of `ActionLink()` (it passes `null` to the `htmlAttributes` parameter but you could also replace `null` with (say) `new { @class = "myclass" }` which would add `class="myclass"` to the html. Suggest you do some research about routing in MVC. If you do not understand the basics of routing you are going to have a lot of problems trying to develop your app.